# Intermittent segmentation faults in main after fork

Tags: c, linux, system-calls

I'm taking a class on how to learn programming multi process programs on linux on university.
I'm still very green and trying my best to learn, so any thing you might see that is wrong would be welcome.

I have a problem that asks me to iterate an array, one half on main process,
the other half on the child process.
I wrote code that does that, but the problem is, i've noticed if i run a few times the binary, the main(father) process from times to times segmentations faults.

Please have a look at the code, and tell me what's wrong with it or if i am missing a key aspect of this type of programming.
My answer starts after the comment //answer starts here.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define ARRAY_SIZE 1000
int main()
{
    int numbers[ARRAY_SIZE]; /* array to lookup */
    int n;                   /* the number to find */
    time_t t;                /* needed to initialize random number generator (RNG) */
    int i;

    /* intializes RNG (srand():stdlib.h; time(): time.h) */
    srand((unsigned)time(&t));

    /* initialize array with random numbers (rand(): stdlib.h) */
    for (i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i++)
        numbers[i] = rand() % 10000;

    /* initialize n */
    n = rand() % 10000;


    //answer starts here
    int half = n / 2;
    int count = 0;
    int pid_status = 0;
    pid_t pid_f = fork();
    if (pid_f == -1)
    {
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    else
    {
        if (pid_f == 0) // child process iterates half end of the array
        {
            for (i = half; i < ARRAY_SIZE; ++i)
            {
                if (numbers[i] == n)
                {
                    count++;
                }
            }
            printf("Sons counter:%d\n", count);
            exit(count);
        } //else it's the father process
        else
        {
            for (i = 0; i < half; ++i)
            {
                if (numbers[i] == n)
                {
                    count++;
                }
            }
            waitpid(pid_f, &pid_status, 0);
            printf("Father counter:%d\n", count);
            if (WIFEXITED(pid_status))
            {
                count += WEXITSTATUS(pid_status);
            }
            printf("Sum is=%d\n", count);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: compile with debug and run under gdb. at least you will see where its failing. And try running under valgrind

Comment: I've ran gdb a few times, can't seem to get it to crash.

I've ran valgrind and it gives me an error,
It tells me that the if on the second for ->

Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)

Address 0xfff001000 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd

Comment: Code that "sometimes SegFaults" is like being "1/2 pregnant", your code is either valid or its not. So anytime "sometimes" comes into play, that means there is something wrong "all the time" that only shows up occasionally.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The segmentation fault is caused by n being out of bounds sometimes:

```
   n = rand() % 10000;


    //answer starts here
    int half = n / 2;
```

Half can be 5000, but numbers is only 1000 elements.

Maybe you meant:

```
 n = rand() % 1000;
```

Comment: I think he means `half = ARRAY_SIZE / 2;`

Comment: Good call! I was focusing in the loops but they looked perfect. And they were, except that they were going out of bound because of this.

Comment: I figured `half` was mixed up in this somewhere, but I hadn't yet figured out how.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a fixed version of your code. Initialize half to half of ARRAY_SIZE, instead of n.

As you said in your code: `int n; /* the number to find */`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define ARRAY_SIZE 1000

int main() {

    int numbers[ARRAY_SIZE]; /* array to lookup */
    int n;                   /* the number to find */
    time_t t;                /* needed to initialize random number generator (RNG) */
    int i;

    srand((unsigned)time(&t));

    for (i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i++) {
        numbers[i] = rand() % 10000;
    }

    /* initialize n */
    n = rand() % 10000;

    int half = ARRAY_SIZE / 2;
    int count = 0;
    int pid_status = 0;
    pid_t pid_f = fork();

    if (pid_f == -1) {
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    } else {
        if (pid_f == 0) {
            for (i = half; i < ARRAY_SIZE; ++i) {
                if (numbers[i] == n) {
                    count++;
                }
            }
            printf("Sons counter:%d\n", count);
            exit(count);
        } else {
            for (i = 0; i < half; ++i) {
                if (numbers[i] == n) {
                    count++;
                }
            }
            waitpid(pid_f, &pid_status, 0);
            printf("Father counter:%d\n", count);
            if (WIFEXITED(pid_status)) {
                count += WEXITSTATUS(pid_status);
            }
            printf("Sum is=%d\n", count);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the person above spotted the bug.